# Java and MySQL Convoluted Setup

Tags: java, mysql, security

I am tasked with writing an application in Java (it is not web hosted, but rather deployed to multiple platforms - this decision is not in my control).

I know Java well enough to do this and MySQL enough to seem clever but is probably dangerous. I am not an expert though which is why I'm here asking for design help with this.

Here are the requirements:

1) The java application will require generic read access to certain tables in a database - This does not need access control

2) The java application will need to be able to modify a few specific tables (not necessarily on the same database - but some are), but only when the user accid matches the rows in that table

3) Due to the nature of the infrastructure the users cannot access the database directly for the read data (though they could for the write data)

How do I give users write access to a table so that they only insert/modify on their account id.

If they have write access to a table they could modify rows that aren't tied to their account id. And while I can set the app to make sure it ties it to their account, if they have write access they can access it outside the app? And if I make a generic write account for the app they could simply view the user/pass in the java code which is as bad?

The infrastructure will not allow me to set up a real server-client communication system (which could handle auth and processing). The the best I can do is background process that only communicates with internal systems. This app will be external. The best I could do is allow the external users access to a database.

I was thinking something like having the app work on a seperate replicated database and then have the background process transfer it to the real one (this doesn't need to be real time so..) but it doesn't solve the inherent security issue with write access.

Is there a way to give users conditional write access to a table (condtiional on their accid matching) wholly within MySQLs security features?

The read data is obviously easy, just open read access to the table. Its the write access I"m not sure about and I'm just hoping I'm missing something.

I appreciate any comment and suggestions. Even if the answer is its not possible.

Thanks.

Comment: You are in a unique and blessed position to be in charge of a large project. Many programmers would feel excited at the chance to learn new techniques and implement them in some highly-visible way. So go study up online and come back to SO when you have solid, technical questions about code (not design). And good luck :)

Comment: @Kon in fact, you can ask for design here as well...

Comment: You may create two database users: one for read permissions only and another for read and write permissions on some tables of your database. Then, in your application, define two connection pools, one for each user, and handle the functionality by the specific database connectivity for the specific type of user.

Comment: I recently read a MariaDB 10 [thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7503736) that went somewhat off-topic talking about [multi-tenant architecture](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7504841). It is not the same as the write access case you describe, but it might give you some ideas.